# how to start term in a separate window at launch

Tags: term

I added the following two lines to my init.el script.

```
(split-window-vertically)
(other-window 1)
```

What I now would like to achieve is to start within the current window a `term-mode` with a bin/bash. How can this be achieved within the init.el? In emacs I run `M-x term` and then I'm asked if /bin/bash should be run, hit enter and a terminal is running. I'm struggling to achieve the same within the init.el. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `(term "/bin/bash")` right after what you already have, and that worked on my setup. So you have:

```
(split-window-vertically)
(other-window 1)
(term "/bin/bash")
```

Your Emacs should start with (probably) the `*scratch*` buffer on top, and a `term-mode` window in a bash shell on the bottom, and your cursor at the command prompt.

Comment: thx, works perfectly!